# Can the initial wavefunction be any function?

Tags: hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Knowing the wavefunction $\Psi(x,y,z,0)$ is enough to know the functions for $\frac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y,z,0)}{\partial{x^2}}$, $\frac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y,z,0)}{\partial{y^2}}$, $\frac{\partial^2\Psi(x,y,z,0)}{\partial{z^2}}$, seeing as how they are second derivatives of the wavefunction with respect to spatial coordinates, but in order to find the function for $\frac{\partial\Psi(x,y,z,0)}{\partial{0}}$ we need to also know the function for the potential operator function $V(x,y,z,0)$, implying that $\frac{\partial\Psi(x,y,z,0)}{\partial{0}}$ is free to take on the wavefunction needed to keep the Schrödinger Equation self consistent.  So if the only requirement for the wavefunction is that it obeys the Schrödinger Equation then it looks like the wavefunction could be any function.

Does this mean that the initial wavefunction $\Psi(x,y,z,0)$ can be any function of $x$, $y$, and $z$, or are there more requirements for the wavefunction in addition to being consistent with the Schrödinger Equation?

Comment: Any function is allowed.

Comment: @ValterMoretti It does have to be square integrable though right?

Comment: It depends.   You may consider the equation as a simple PDE or you can require also the standard quantum interpretation. In the second case you must also assume the $L^2$ property.

Comment: Unfortunately, square-integrability (i.e. $L^2$) is too small of a space for even the most basic quantum systems. I elaborated a little more in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is going to be a valid, Hilbert space solution to a Schrodinger equation, then it must be square integrable (or at least Dirac normalizable) and must satisfy the boundary conditions of the particular situation.

For example, for the 1D infinite square well of width $a$, with $V(x)=0, 0 < x < a$, the function $A\cos( Bx)$, by itself, would not be a solution because it doesn't fit the boundary conditions at $x=0$. A combination of sin and cos would work.

Comment: I looked up what square integrable means and found that it means that the integral of the square of the absolute value of a function is finite.  The integral of $Ae^{i(kr)}$ is infinite, for any non zero $A$, so does this mean that it isn't a valid wavefunction?

Comment: @AndersGustafson indeed, over an infinite domain the plane wave $e^{ikx}$ is not normalizable and is not a valid wave function. Similarly $\delta(x)$ does not count. But sometimes we play this trick: we consider Gaussian wave packets $\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}+ikx\right)$ for large or small $\sigma,$ in one limit these act like the plane wave and in the other limit these act like the Dirac $\delta.$ We can then be sloppy and ignore the envelope for the sake of the physics, and we get expressions of perfectly definite position and perfectly indefinite momentum, or vice versa.

Comment: Obviously this extremely common example has a valid wave function. $L^2$ normalization applies to elements of $L^2$. Many wave functions, such as your example, are perfectly valid wave functions that belong to a vector space bigger than $L^2$. I elaborated further in an answer.

I'd suggest taking what introductory quantum mechanics textbooks say about such topics with a large grain of salt. These are relatively advanced ideas in analysis that many such books rush through incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, it depends. In the generally accepted literature for non-relativistic quantum mechanics, quantum states are elements of the symmetric (or anti-symmetric) tensor algebra of a separable Hilbert space. There of course exists research considering more exotic spaces of states. Anyways, let's talk informally about the space of states $H$. If you want full rigor, this question has been asked and formally answered many times on math stackexchange and elsewhere; this answer is meant to give only a rough idea.

The space of states $H$ is larger than $L^2(\Omega)$; I won't bother specifying where you want the functions to map to/from, $\Omega$. As was noted in the comments, there are elementary examples of wave functions which are not square-integrable. Depending how far down the rabbit hole you want to go, separability is enough or you may want to look at what is formally called a Gelfand triple (aka a rigged Hilbert space) which, consists of a particular subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$, $L^2(\Omega)$ itself, and the dual of the smaller space which contains distributions.

The idea of *distributions* was introduced by Dirac. They are not formally functions as the Wikipedia page incorrectly notes for the Dirac Delta <s>function</s>. After mathematicians saw how useful distributions are, Dirac's idea essentially created an entire field of mathematics; distributions are now formalized, well-studied objects.

Relatedly, $L^2(\Omega)$ itself is not a space of functions per se, but rather one of equivalence classes of functions, where square-integrable functions are defined as equivalent if they differ only by sets of measure zero. It is a nice space of functions for physicists, in particular, because it is self-dual. That is, the bra (a linear functional $L^2(\Omega)\rightarrow\Omega$) of a particular ket in $L^2(\Omega)$ is also in $L^2(\Omega)$.